# How to get id of created image in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

I have a Recipe model and RecipePhoto model. I want to show the thumbnail of  scaled image on creating a new recipe. I upload photo through jquery-file-upload. The problem is that i don't know how to get the id of uploaded photo.

**Example:**

User is creating a new recipe. He loads a photo and it crops on server and he see thumbnail preview before submitting recipe.

recipes_controller.rb

```
 def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    @recipe_photo = RecipePhoto.new
  end
```

recipes/new.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, :html => {:class => 'add-recipe-form'} do |recipe|
  .form-inputs
    = recipe.input :title

  .form-actions
  = recipe.submit "Create recipe"

= form_for @recipe_photo do |f|

  .form-inputs
    = f.label :image, "Upload paintings:"
    = f.file_field :image, multiple: false
```

recipe_photo.js.coffee (Here i can get only filename, not record_id)

```
$ ->
  $('.new_recipe_photo').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    done: (e, data) ->
      console.log data.files[0], data.files[0].name
```

recipe_photo.rb

```
class RecipePhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :recipe_id, :image

  belongs_to :recipe

  mount_uploader :image, RecipeImageUploader


end
```

Comment: Did you mount your uploader to the recipe model?

Comment: no i mount it to my recipe photo model. i've update my question.

Comment: What do you have in your controller params?, I had same problem and when I inspected params I saw content-type in header was not set to multipart/form-data, so my image param was being sent as just the filename and not file content. Finally I had to go with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/FileReader.

Comment: i have valid image/jpeg in my params. The problem is how can i know image id after saving. Image is saving ok and i have record in db.